# How Do I Set the Class Name of a Python wxWidgets Application Window?

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython, wxwidgets

I need to set the class name of a Python wxWidgets application window on Linux (Ubuntu). By default it is set to "python."

I have tried calling the SetAppName() and SetClassName() methods on the app object, but this does not seem to have any effect.

Basically what I am trying to do is change the application window's class name to a custom value so I can associate it with its icon in Cairo dock.

The application is Pronterface (https://github.com/kliment/Printrun).

### Some More Details

---

Basically right now I have a launcher icon on Cairo dock that has the correct icon for Pronterface (I can set the icon manually).

The problem is when I launch Pronterface Cairo dock doesn't associate the Pronterface window with the launcher. It creates a new icon on the launcher with the Python logo for the window.

There is a launcher option to enter a program class name (and a tool to grab it from an open window) so that Cairo dock can identify windows that belong to the launcher.

Problem is that the Pronterface's class name is "python" which, if I use it, causes the Pronterface launcher to be associated with any wxWidget python application (or probably any python UI application), not just Pronterface windows.

That's why I want to change the class name.

Comment: So you're looking to re-title the window that the GUI is run on? Where, for example, it's "StackOverflow.com | Google Chrome" for Chrome?

Comment: @TankorSmash - No, the window title text is already a custom value ("Pronterface"). There is another value for the class name, which it seems by default is "python" unless it is changed. Because of this Cairo dock can't pick out the Pronterface window from other python windows unless I change it to a custom value.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the wx.App's SetAppName() method. Alternatively, there's also the frame's SetTitle() method, but I am guessing you tried that already.

**EDIT:**

I asked about this on [wxPython-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxpython-dev/Wo-UB_CGeCQ) and they reminded me of something I recall from Windows. You may need to freeze your application using something like PyInstaller to get it to work correctly. On the other hand, this is what Robin Dunn, creator of wxPython had to say:

*Way down deep inside the X11 libraries applications and windows can be
assigned a string to be used as a class name.  In the olden days when
the Motif toolkit was king it was very common to allow user
customization of the UI elements in an application using their
.Xdefaults file.  It was much like how CSS is today, where you could set
the colors, fonts or other attributes for an item.  If the widget names
and class names were set by the application programmer then the
properties could be set for all elements of a certain type like a
button, or all elements that have a specific class name, and you could
also specify a widget or class (or all of them) within a certain
containment hierarchy, etc.*

*All of that is still there under the covers down in the X and Xt
libraries, but I'm not familiar with how (or if) GTK exposes that or
makes use of it itself.  In the old wxMotif port wx set the X widget
name using whatever was passed to the SetName method, but I don't think
it is doing anything special in the wxGTK port with the name.*

Comment: Yes, both the SetAppName() and SetTitle() have been tried. The Cairo dock grab class name tool still returns "python" as the class name.

Comment: No, setting properties is what was done in the .Xdefaults (not .Xresorces, I misremembered) file.  The class names need to be set in the code and I don't think that is exposed in the wxGTK API. (But SetName would be the place for it if it is ever supported.)  Check with wx-users to be sure.

Comment: Ok...I fixed the quote.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll - Thanks for taking the time to ask on wxPython-dev. That info is helpful. I'll dig into it a little more. I thought the fix was probably something quick and easy. It doesn't affect my use of the software, just a nice to have I thought I'd add.